# How to iterate through a `DataView.RowFilter` and extract values from specific cells in each row

Tags: c#, foreach, datagridview

I am trying to iterate through a `RowFilter` and extract values from specific cells in each row with the code below.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var Dt = sIMSDataSet.Stock;
            var Dv = new DataView(Dt);
            Dv.RowFilter = "CheckedOutUntil = " + "'" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy") + "'";
            dataGridView1.DataSource = Dv;

            foreach (var row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                var date = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[16].Value.ToString();
                var itemName = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                var Email = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[15].Value.ToString();

                SendEmail(date, itemName, Email);
            }
        }
```

The filter works just fine, however. The issue i am having is that the `for each` loop, instead of it iterating through each row it just loops through the first row for the number of rows returned.

What to happen is that `date` `itemName` and `Email` should be the value of each seperte row returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a foreach loop but then not using the `row` variable in it.
You're only ever using the first row because you are using `dataGridView1.Rows[0]` instead of `row`. Make that replacement and you will see the functionality you had intended.

```
foreach (var row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    var date = row.Cells[16].Value.ToString();
    var itemName = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    var Email = row.Cells[15].Value.ToString();
    SendEmail(date, itemName, Email);
}
```

Comment: When i use row in `dataGridView1.Rows[row]` i get the error "cannot covert from object to int", and if i use `int rowTosearch = Convert.ToInt16(row);` it throws an exception

Comment: `row` is of type `DataGridViewRow`, you'll want to use it like this: `var date = row.Cells[16].Value.ToString();`